# Javascript date object in different locale and timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, dst

I need to write a web application that show events of people in different locale. I almost finished it, but there're 2 problems with date:

- using date javascript object, the date depends on user computer settings and it's not reliable
- if there's an event in a place with dfferent timezone respect user current position, i have to print it inside `()`. Is it possible in javascript to build a date object with a given timezone and daylight settings?

I also find some workaround, such as jsdate and date webservices, but they don't overcome the problem of having a javascript object with the correct timezone and daylight settings (for date operation such as adding days and so on).

Answer (score 6):

A couple of things to keep in mind.

**Store all event datetimes in UTC time**

Yes, there is no getting around this.

**Find out all the timezones...**

...of all the users in the system. You can use the following detection script: http://site.pageloom.com/automatic-timezone-detection-with-javascript. It will hand you a timezone key such as for example "America/Phoenix".

In your case you need to store the timezone together with the event, since a user may switch timezone - but the event will always have happened in a specific one. (argh)

**Choose your display mechanism**

If you want to localize your event dates with Javascript, there is a nifty library for that too (which can use the keys supplied with the previous script). Here: https://github.com/mde/timezone-js.

with that library you can for example do this:

```
var dt = new timezoneJS.Date(UTC_TIMESTAMP, 'America/New_York');
```

or

```
var dt = new timezoneJS.Date(2006, 9, 29, 1, 59, 'America/Los_Angeles');
```

where UTC_TIMESTAMP for example could be `1193855400000`. And `America/New_York`is the timezone you have detected when the event took place.

The `dt` object that you get from this will behave as a normal JavaScript `Date` object. But will automatically "correct" itself to the timezone you have specified (including DST).

If you want to, you can do all the corrections in the backend - before you serve the page. Since I don't know what programming language you are using there, I cannot give you any immediate tips. But basically it follows the same logic, if you know the timezone, and the UTC datetime -> you can localize the datetime. All programming languages have libraries for that.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the point of a Date object.  It represents a particular point in time.  As I speak, it is 1308150623182 all over the world.  Timezone only comes into play when you want to *display* the time to the user.  An operation like "adding a day" does not involve the time zone at all.

Comment: Adding a day does indeed involve time zone.  Not all days are 24 hours in length.  Depending on time zone, daylight saving rules, and the particular date in question, a calendar day might be 23, 24, or 25 hours in length (or other strange values if talking about historical time zones).  So it's not always a simple matter of adding 86400000.

Comment: Maybe the question is underspecified. If it's 2:30 in the morning, the day before the time-zone shifts forward, what does "adding a day" mean?

Comment: Exactly.  If you mean "adding 24 hours", then you're fine.  But most people think of these transitions as being invisible because they are usually asleep when they occur.  So if you ask a layman what time it will be 1 day from 2:30 AM, they are going to expect 2:30 AM - not the possible 1:30 AM or 3:30AM.  People tend to think in terms of calendars, even when those calendars are shifty. :)

Comment: @MattJohnson -- I guess that's why you don't *ask* laymen: they give unhelpful answers.  (I was in a product meeting yesterday and asked how we should handle an edge case for a system that supported 700,000 users and the PM dismissed it saying, "90% of the time, that doesn't happened."  I almost strangled her.)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility might be to use UTC date and time for everything.  That way, there is nothing to convert.

Another is to have your server provide the time and date.  Then you don't have to depend on the user to have it set correctly, and you don't have to worry about where your user's timezone is.

Answer (score -1):

Use `getUTCDate()`, `getUTCHours()`, ... instead of `getDate()`, `getHours()`,...
`getTimetoneOffset()` could be useful, too.