# Date timezone conversion socket.io

Tags: node.js, date, timezone, chat, socket.io

I'm writing a chat program using node.js and socket.io. When a user sends a message, I'd like the time at which they sent it to be emitted. Instead of the Date data being in the timezone of the person who sent it, however, I'd like it to be converted to the timezones of the respective recievers. Will JavaScript take care of this automatically, or is it something I need to fix?

```
socket.emit('chat', {
    message: 'message',
    date: new Date()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply send the UTC value from the `Date` back to your server and up to another client.  Even if they have different time zones, the local client will convert from the UTC value to that time zone when the `Date` is displayed.

It is important that the date is sent as UTC and not in the local time zone.

- This can be an integer number (which will be milliseconds since 1/1/1970 UTC), obtained from `.getTime()`.  All browsers support this, but it's not a very human readable format.
- It can also be a string in ISO8601/RFC3339 format at UTC, such as `2013-06-26T15:40:00Z`, which can be obtained by `.toISOString()`.

What you *can't* do is just pass a `Date` object directly, as you showed in your sample.  Socket.io will just call `.toString()` on it.  That will end up sending a human readable RFC822 formatted string with the *local* time zone - not the UTC value that you want.

Comment: Your "According to this" link is broke. I seem to be experiencing this issue with socket.io. Any new link or info?

Comment: @BradW - My answer was originally written back in 2013.  It appears that the repo has moved, and for some unknown reason, issue 804 was deleted.   I have edited my answer to remove that link, as well as the other details that are no longer relevant.  The solution is simply not to pass `Date` objects, but rather call `.toISOString()` or `.getTime()` on it and pass that instead.

Comment: Calling `.toISOString()` before sending it over socket.io solved my issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Javascript date object in different locale and timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356839/javascript-date-object-in-different-locale-and-timezone)

This answer looks good. Store all your dates as UTC and then translate to receivers time zone.