# Does .toLocaleDateString() automatically format date based on location?

Tags: javascript

If I run `new Date().toLocaleDateString()`, I receive "1/16/2020.
If someone in a country with the date format of DD/MM/YYYY (16/1/2020) ran my code, would it automatically swap the day and month?

Comment: Not based on location, but based on [locale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale_(computer_software)).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript date object in different locale and timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356839/javascript-date-object-in-different-locale-and-timezone)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not specify a `locale` argument, then the result is based on the user's **browser default locale**. While this may correspond to location more often than not, it is **not *guaranteed* to match their current location**. It is a user preference.

For example, a British person living abroad in the US may choose to set their browser locale to `en-GB`. In this case, `.toLocaleDateString()` would return the date as `DD/MM/YYYY` despite the user being in the US.

You can determine a user's current locale through the [`Navigator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator) interface:

```js
const getBrowserLocale = () => navigator.language || navigator.browserLanguage || (navigator.languages || ["en"])[0]

console.log( getBrowserLocale() );
```

For more info, see the docs: [**`.toLocaleDateString()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)